# on_press() Listener need to reference object not created in on_press()

Tags: python, scope, keyboard-events, onpress

**Problem:**

catch on_press() on text box and either define global to reference, then display the keyboard value in the text box.

The 'myObjectText' is defined in another function, so
**HOW TO reference the object 'myObjectText' inside the on_press() event**?

Use pynput library; but on open to ideas.

```
def on_press(key):
    try:
        if insidePoint(key, myObjectText):
            myObjectText = key.char()
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(key))
```

**Listener on_press defined:**

Listener in main driver function, to list to on_press()

```
    with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

**Text object defined:**

creating 'myObjectText' in custom function

```
def makeTextGUI():
    
    win = GraphWin("",300,200)        
    myObjectText = Text(Point(225,70),"")
    myObjectText.draw(win)
```

**Imports:**

```
from graphics import *
from pynput import mouse
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
```

Comment: what is `myObjectText`? If you want to assign to global `myObjectText` then you need `global myObjectText` inside function. Without `global myObjectText` it creates local variable `myObjectText`.

Comment: don't you get error message when you use `myObjectText`?

Comment: if you want to change text in objec `Text()` then you CAN'T assing new value but you have to use correct functions for this. probably `myObjectText["text"] = ...`

Comment: if you want to get key when active is `GraphWin` then you don't need `pyniput` but `events` and `bind()` in `GraphWin`

Comment: BTW: it needs `myObjectText.getText()` and `myObjectText.setText(key.char())`. But problem is: Graphics (similar to other GUIs) doesn't like to use widgets in separated threads - but `Listener` runs all code in separated thread.

Comment: if you need to put text in window then maybe use `Entry()` instead of `Text()`